# How to combine multiple sql queries into an efficient one

Tags: sql

I want to get all values in a column named "Revision" from 3 tables. Data, Data_File and Data_Storage. So, there an efficient method to do that other than writing

```
Select REV from Data, Data_File and Data_Storage where Data_Num = ?;
```

Is this a situation where I should be using Joins?

Comment: you use union all in this case. select rev from data union all select rev from data_file union all select rev from data_storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are writing will not work, for various reasons.

I suspect that you want:

```
select REV from Data where Data_Num = ?
UNION ALL
select REV from Data_File where Data_Num = ?
UNION ALL
select REV from Data_Storage where Data_Num = ?
```

Note that you will need to include the parameter three times in the query.